# How to remove cron task that deletes PHP sessions

Tags: cron, php

It seems Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia Cinnamon wants to clear out PHP session files every half-hour.

How do I:

- Remove this task from the scheduler's awareness, and
- Not have to reboot the computer to do so.

I found the crontab file at `/etc/cron.d/php`.

I edited the file by making the relevant line a comment. I expected that now that there is no information in this crontab file that would establish when it should trigger the task, not even the scheduler(?) would keep aware of it.

```bsh
# 09,39 *     * * *     root   [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi
```

The cron process(?) noticed the new file timestamp and reloaded the file (as seen in the syslog).

But the scheduler is still logging in syslog.

```
Mar  6 01:09:07 BrownBunny systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Mar  6 01:09:08 BrownBunny systemd[1]: Started Clean php session files.
```

(which I do not know where to look for those phrases).

I tried the command:

```
sudo service cron reload
```

The PHP session files were still cleaned up.

I can move the php crontab file out of `cron.d`. Considering the above, would this even work?

Notes: I am cross-posting this question [from LinuxMint Forums](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=313704):

Note: This question is copied over from Ask Ubuntu because they consider it not really applicable to Ubuntu.

Comment: That cron will not run if you have `systemd` available, as the test `if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]` would fail.  This is because `systemd` has it's own method to schedule the PHP session cleanup, and your posted log mentioned that the command was run by `systemd` and not `cron`.  Check `systemctl status phpsessionclean` or `systemctl status phpsessionclean.timer`, I do not recall the exact name and do not have a compatible system in front of me.

Comment: @GracefulRestart - Thank you! Using `systemctl` to stop and disable both `phpsessionclean.service` and `phpsessionclean.timer` worked. If you would, write this up as an answer and I will accept it. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `phpsessionclean` scripts as delivered by upstream Debian will either use cron if there is no `systemd` present, or will use `systemd` for scheduling if it is available.

This is apparent in the cronjob test `if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]` which checks if `systemd` has been initialized on this system.

When `systemd` is available, `phpsessionclean` has a service unit (`phpsessionclean.service`) in addition to a timer unit (`phpsessionclean.timer`).  Stopping and disabling both of these, should stop the scheduled task from running within `systemd`:

```
systemctl stop phpsessionclean.service
systemctl disable phpsessionclean.service
systemctl stop phpsessionclean.timer
systemctl disable phpsessionclean.timer
```

Comment: Curious to know why on earth it was ever set this way to start with, given that I don't have or use any client-side PHP.

Comment: @PeterFlynn probably because php* package installed? for me because it was `php-cli` installed